# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object this occurs in a custom Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Good evening community!

I'm currently getting this error when I attempt to use my custom hook.

This custom hook takes 3 parameters, an initial state, a validation rule, and an action function.

at the moment to validate my data appears as undefined.

```
//This is the custom Hook! 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useValidacion = (stateInicial, validar, fn) => {

const [ valores, guardarValores ] = useState(stateInicial);
const [ errores, guardarErrores ] = useState({});
const [ submitForm, guardarSubmitForm ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if(submitForm) {
        const noErrores = Object.keys(errores).lenght === 0;

        if(noErrores) {
            fn(); //Funcion que se este ejecutando
        }
        guardarSubmitForm(false);
    }
}, [errores])

// Funcion que se ejecuta cuando el usuario escribe

const handleChange = e => {
    guardarValores({
        ...valores,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}

//Funcion que se ejecuta cuando el usuario da submit

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const erroresValidacion = validar(valores);
    guardarErrores(erroresValidacion);
    guardarSubmitForm(true);
}

return {
    valores,
    errores,
    submitForm,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit
}
}
 
export default useValidacion;
```

and these are the rules:

```
export default function validarCrearCuenta(valores) {

let errores = {};

// Validar el nombre 

if(valores.nombre.trim() === '') {
    errores.nombre = "El nombre es obligatorio"
}

// Validar el correo 

if(!valores.email.trim() === '') {
    errores.email = "El correo es obligatorio"
} else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(valores.email)) {
    errores.email = "Correo no valido"
} 

// Validar contraseña

if(!valores.password === '') {
    errores.password = "La contraseña es obligatorio"
} else if(valores.password.lenght < 6) {
    errores.password = "La contraseña debe ser de al menos 6 caracteres"
}
}
```

I would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: You have a little typo in the UseEffect function. const noErrores = Object.keys(errores).lenght === 0;
Should be const noErrores = Object.keys(errores).length === 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `validar` ever return null or undefined?

It's likely that `errores` becomes null or undefined at some point, probably when it is set to the return value of `validar(valores)` in `handleSubmit`.

Then we call `Object.keys(null)` in the `useEffect`, and that causes the error.

EDIT: Ah, yes I see the `validar` function is not returning a value. Just add `return errores` at the end.

Comment: Really appreciate it, you were totally right. Thank you

Comment: No problem! And if you're happy with the answer you can mark it as accepted.